# Is it possible to perform a KS-Test in R on Tableau?

Tags: r, tableau-api, kolmogorov-smirnov

My code:

```
SCRIPT_REAL
(

"
a <- (.arg1);
b <-(ks.test((a), 'pnorm', mean(a), sd(a) ));
c <- (b[2]);
d <- (c[[1]]);
d; 
"
,
SUM([Data Column])
)
```

If you run the set of commands between the quotes `" "` in R,
only replace `(.arg1)` with `(norm(100))`, you will see that the function is working fine and the `d` variable output will return only one single numeric value (which is the p-value in this case).

I have no clue why such these functions are not working in Tableau desktop. What's the purpose then of integrating R with Tableau?

Comment: A p value wouldn't be an int.

Comment: Hey @Dason , you are right. I did edit my question for clarifying this, Thank you. although the problem is still happening even if the script is a real number.